# pdf template for automatized pdf generation

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I would like automatize pdf generation. To be more specific, I created a simple pdf form (via Acrobat) in which I have an image of an object, and a text of its description.  Following that I ask different questions in the form.

My problem is: I have a thousand of objects and I want to regenerate this form (with same questions and everything) by simply replacing the text and image of other objects one by one (by calling from db or simply folder). Is it possible?

In other words, I prepare a template and I would like to associate different images and text to two specific fields. Is there an automatic way to do that?

Comment: What programming language are you using?  That will help with suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I realy understand the whole question, but AFAIK the PDF auto generation routines are included in some programing languages. I would choose the PHP, while it has good modules to connect databases and it can run either the server application either the CLI scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do with Acrobate but, knowing Microsoft, there are simple ways to do : https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/converting-web-pages-pdf.html

In this case, generate HTML with a PHP for + db (yes you can).

```
id |    text    |             img
1  | Doodoo doo | C:\Users\Doo\Desktop\img.png
1  | Scooby doo | C:\Users\Doo\Desktop\img2.png
2  | Dydooo doo | C:\Users\Doo\Desktop\img3.png
```

Something like (not perfect of course) :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mycss.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
         $cnx = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Doobydatabase','root','rootpwd');
         $cnx->query('SET NAMES utf8');
         $cnx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $test = $cnx->prepare('Select * from Doo where id=:id');
        $test-> bindValue(':id',$anIdHere);
        $test-> execute();
        $data = $test->fetch(); 

        do{
            //Your HTML Template
        }
        while($data = $test->fetch());
    ?>
    </head>
    </html>
```

Once generated, use the HTML export in Adobe Acrobate. 
You can use too :

- Online Editor : http://html2pdf.com/fr/
- PHP library : https://www.html2pdf.fr/
- PhantomJS solution for a complete automation : https://aboullaite.me/phantomjs-generate-pixel-perfect-pdf-reports/

I know there will be better answer, but I begin to give you informations I have, cause I was looking for this few weeks ago.

*In my case, I have chosen phantomJS, now i just have to give my script an ID, and PhantomJS self generate a PDF. But if you want something simple, choose Acrobate or an Online Editor.*